# How to create a unit test for a param decorator in NestJs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, nestjs

I would like to create a unit test for a very simple custom decorator, but I can't.
My decorator was born following the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55560858/in-nest-js-is-it-possible-to-get-service-instance-inside-a-param-decorator).
I have authentication via Keycloak and with this solution in my controllers I can get the user object corresponding to the token.

I then use the decorator like this:

```js
import {
  Body,
  Controller,
  Post,
  UseGuards,
  UsePipes,
  ValidationPipe,
} from '@nestjs/common'
import { LogbooksService } from './logbooks.service'
import { User } from 'src/typeorm/user.entity'
import { AuthUser } from 'src/users/users.decorator'
import { UsersGuard } from 'src/users/users.guard'
import { CreateLogbookDto } from './dto/CreateLogbook.dto'

@Controller('logbooks')
export class LogbooksController {
  constructor(private readonly logbookService: LogbooksService) {}

  @Post()
  @UseGuards(UsersGuard)
  @UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
  async createLogbook(
    @Body() createLogbookDto: CreateLogbookDto,
    @AuthUser('user') user: User,
  ) {
    const newLogbook = await this.logbookService.createLogbook(
      createLogbookDto,
      user,
    )
    return newLogbook
  }
}
```

And this is the simple decorator

```js
import { createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common'

export const AuthUser = createParamDecorator((data: string, req) => {
  return req.args[0].principal
})
```

The nest version is 10.2.1

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. that decorator is outdated and will not work in Nest v10. The `req` being the second parameter for Nest v7 if I recall correctly. The new custom decorator should be:

```js
export const AuthUser = createParamDecorator((data: string, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
  const req = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest()
  return req[data].principle
})
```

As that will get `req.user.principle` like you're trying to.

2. There's not an easy way to make a unit test for something like this, other than extracting out the callback passed to `createParamDecorator`, which is an option, but this is better tested via integration or e2e tests that actually send requests to the server

Comment: `req[data].principal` doesn't work it's undefiend, it's ok with `req.principal` beacuse in guard I put the user retrieved with service in req.principal.
Too bad it's not possible to do a unit test, so that leaves uncovered code

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't possible, I said it wasn't easy. I was assuming `req[data].principle` based on your original code, thinking that you had this assigned at `req.user.principle`, but re-reading the code, I see that `args[0]` is the `ExecutionContext#args[0]` which is indeed the `request` obejct

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
function getParamDecoratorFactory(decorator: unknown) {
    class TestDecorator {
      public test(@AuthUser() value) {
        console.log(value)
        console.log(decorator)
      }
    }

    const args = Reflect.getMetadata(ROUTE_ARGS_METADATA, TestDecorator, 'test')
    return args[Object.keys(args)[0]].factory
  }
...Creating Test Module

describe('decorator', () => {
    it('Decorator Test', () => {
      const req = httpMock.createRequest()
      const res = httpMock.createResponse()
      req.user = { principal: {} }
      const ctx = new ExecutionContextHost(
        [req, res],
        LogbooksController,
        logbookController.createLogbook,
      )
      const factory = getParamDecoratorFactory(AuthUser)
      user = factory('user', ctx)
    })
  })
```